# PL/SQL returning a list in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I need a CASE statement to return a list of strings but I'm having some syntax problems. The resulting SQL should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM FRUIT WHERE COLOR IN ('RED', 'YELLOW')
```

What I'm trying to do (this doesn't work):

```
SELECT * FROM FRUIT WHERE COLOR IN
CASE
    WHEN TYPE = *something*
    THEN ('RED', 'YELLOW')
    ELSE ('GREEN')
END
```

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM FRUIT WHERE COLOR IN
CASE
    WHEN TYPE = 1
    THEN 'RED'
    ELSE 'GREEN'
END
```

The error I'm getting:

```
ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis
```

It works when I use multiple COLOR = 'X' OR COLOR = 'Y' but I was wondering if there was a way to use only one CASE statement for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use boolean logic instead. No advantage in using a case expression.

Comment: Why don't use unions? When you need to query from one table but with case where clauses - unions is most common way to go.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @Used_By_Already yeah, I will take that approach. Thanks.

Comment: @Ychdziu The real SQL expression I am working on is far longer that this example so I wanted an smaller, easier to maintain as possible. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I was expecting a smaller, easier to maintain statement like the first one on my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Case` statement can only return one value. I think you don't need `CASE` statement , you can use `IN` operation instead of `Case`, like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM FRUIT 
WHERE TYPE = 'something'  AND COLOR IN ('RED', 'YELLOW') 
OR TYPE <> 'something'  AND COLOR IN ('GREEN')
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I will use this approach. Thank you, I will accept your answer.